# Creating a jar file in IntelliJ 12.1.4?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have seen several of this question asked here, but none have fully been answered to my necessity. I have a file I want to create a jar file with so I can simply place it on my desktop and run it. I think I understand the process up to using Process Structure, then I am lost.

Comment: Are you using maven or do you want to do this purely with Intellij?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can generate an artifact in IntelliJ from the build menu -> build artifact.

Dependending on your project, possible artifacts may be found automatically or not (if you use a "build tool" like maven, ant or gradle).

In case of a build tool, check its documentation to find how to generate a jar file from it.

If you're using a pure IntelliJ project, select your project root and hit F4, it will open its  settings. In Artifacts, you'll have to add a new jar (the green + at the top of the window). Select "From modules and dependencies...". Then, you'll have to select the module to use and its main class. It should be enough. Then, you'll just have to build the needed artifact. The jar file will be generated in the folder defined in the configuration (Project settings->Project, Project compiler output in case of a single module, otherwise it will be generated in the module's folder)

When you're looking for a feature in IntelliJ, don't forget to use ctrl+shift+A to search it by its name.

Hope it helps